# Declaring an array in an if statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I'm very new to java and am trying to use if statements do decide which variables are in my array.

```
if (count<2){
                int blockA = arrayOne[x-1][y];
                int blockB = arrayOne[x-1][y];
                int blockC = arrayOne[x][y-1];
                int blockD = arrayOne[x][y+1];

                int[] checker = {blockA,blockB,blockC,
                    blockD};
                checkCount = 4;
            }
            else {
                int blockE = arrayOne[x+1][y];
                int blockF = arrayOne[x-1][y];
                int blockG = arrayOne[x][y+1];

                int[] checker = {blockE,blockF,blockG};
                checkCount = 3;
            }
```

but every time I compile it comes up saying "cannot find symbol" and is talking about when I use the checker array later on, arrayOne contains only numbers.
Is there a way to make this work without using a funciton?
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring the array in the scope of the `if` or `else` statement.

When the closing `}` is reached that scope no longer exists, thus the variable is no longer available.

Declare the variable *outside* of the `if` statement and *initialize* it in the `if` statement.

Care must be taken to ensure it's initialized for all execution paths.